# Java and Japanese characters  

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, cjk

I'm using Struts in my application and JSON. When I try to submit Japanese characters, in my controller class I get a string like that:

```
&#12373 ; &#12383 ; &#12399 ; &#12414 ; &#12419 ; &#12425 ;  (without spaces)
```

I should convert it to Japanese characters, but I couldn't find how to do that!

Please can anyone help me?

Comment: check the encoding of the characters in your files

Comment: I would convert it in Java controller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the XML encoding for unicode. Use the [Apache Commons library](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) to unescape it:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;

String input = "&#12373; &#12383; &#12399; &#12414; &#12419; &#12425;";
String plain = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(input);
System.out.println(plain); // Will print your characters
```